# form:input tag throwing error spring mvc

Tags: javascript, html, spring, forms, spring-mvc

I have the following tags and they work fine

```
<tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="form-control" id="1" name="x1" type="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off"/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" id="2" name="x2" type="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off"/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" id="3" name="x3" type="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off"/></td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

these sit within a form:form tag. And the page loads fine.

However when I switch these tags to form:input as below

```
<tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><form:input class="form-control" id="1" path="x1" type="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

I get the following error in my logs

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path 

[/xxx] threw exception [/WEB-INF/views/targets/xxx.jsp (line: 70, column: 115) Unterminated &lt;form:input tag] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/targets/xxx.jsp (line: 70, column: 115) Unterminated &lt;form:input tag
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:985)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1267)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElementsScriptless(Parser.java:1495)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1413)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1658)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:995)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1267)
```

On the same form outside of the table I have a form input tag that works fine

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label smaller" for="x">x</label>
                    <form:input class="form-control single" id="x" path="x" type="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off"/>
                </div>
```

Have changed ids and path params ectra for brevity. I cannot use normal input tags as these will not populate the form when returning from the server.

I can post the whole page if required but have tried the page replacing the form:input tag with input in the table as above and it works fine but for some reason does not like the form:input

Any ideas Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all replace class attribute by cssClass within form:input tag. Please make sure that all tags within table are closed properly. There is no reason of form:input tag not working within td tag.

Comment: I am not really sure what it was I just copied one of the form:input tags that was working and duplicated it as required and this seemed to work.